# Umlaut in folder name

Tags: r, rstudio

Unfortunately someone created a folder using umlaut and I can't change it's name, but I need to read all the files it contains. R4.2 is not happy about the umlaut (I am already using UTF-8 encoding). Any known solution?

```r
c("sähköpyörä")
#> [1] "s<U+00E4>hk<U+00F6>py<U+00F6>r<U+00E4>"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Change the locale settings , but before you do it. Please backup your current locale settings. If I run this code I am exactly getting German(If I am not mistaken that they are German indeed) as you typed in your question. So it seems changing locale might help you.

Comment: Try: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","en_GB.UTF-8")`

Comment: You should post the result of `sessionInfo()` in your question.

Comment: The solution proposed by @PKumar solved the problem and indeed it is a folder in a German server.

Comment: This is what solved the problem even after restarting R/RStudio: `usethis::edit_r_environ()` then changed `LC_ALL` to `LC_ALL="en_GB.utf8"`